# Off-canvas / viewport navigation slide in with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make an off-canvas navigation that slides in from the left to take up 20% of the page while the content slides to the left ( some of it will be off canvas ) taking up 80% of the page.
This has been seen in Google's mobile site and Facebook's mobile app.

Here is a version using CSS3 Transitions: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/umEgv

Except, I am trying to make one that relies only on JQuery / Javascript and not CSS Transitions at all.

Below is a link to what I have so far.

I don't understand why it is not working. The width of the #main-nav should be toggled every time .menu-button is clicked; thus creating a sliding tot he right effect.

Can someone please help me fix this and / or help me with that I am trying to achieve.

Here is what I have so far: http://pastebin.com/0X7uT7tC

Comment: The CSS version refers to [http://jpanelmenu.com/](http://jpanelmenu.com/). Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed width to 20% in css and then hide this on load.

[**HERE IS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aaaheatair/k3NnN/)

**jQuery**

```
 $('#main-nav').hide();
 $('.menu-button').click(function () {
     $('#main-nav').animate({
         width: 'toggle'
     });
 });
```

**CSS**

```
    .main-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #3B3B3B;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Ah okay, it works. Except one problem. The first and second <li> in the nav are missing, even in the fiddle.



Also, do you have any idea how I can move the content to the right simultaneously? So that the left edge of the content is off the screen ( exactly 20% is off the screen ) ? Because then the viewport's 100% width will be composed of 20% now showing navigation and 80% content.

Comment: first to move menu `top: 85px;` or something like that. I will set up a page shift for you. be back in a few.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed to get me started! :-) Now, I just need to apply some customisations, thank you!